# Change color of all object in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I have some TextBlock, Grid, TextBox, etc in my pages . I want to change their colors in all page because I have a setting for change color in my app. How can I change color all of them in all pages with code?
I search a little for data Binding But I couldn't understand something. (I am 
amateur)
please help me?

Comment: Either you need to change color every time when app in use or once changed should be reflected in next launch of app also?

Comment: I have setting page in my app. person choose color of app and I change color of all object in my app. If it is necessary to restart app, I do that But How can I change Color. this is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a SolidColorBrush key in your resource dictionary.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DynamicBrush" Color="White"/>
```

Initially give the color as what you need and bind it to controls in all pages. When user tends to change the color then you can change the key value in your resource dictionary which will be reflected in pages where all you have used that key.

XAML

```
<Button Content="change" x:Name="BtnChange" Click="BtnChange_Click"/>
```

C#

```
private void BtnChange_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        App.Current.Resources["DynamicBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        this.Foreground = App.Current.Resources["DynamicBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
    }
```

This will help you.

Comment: It's good. Is there any way to update automatically. It's work and I use background = "{StaticResource AccentColor}". But when I change resource, I have to set it to my button again? either way, thanks.

Comment: Am not able to get a soln for this. Once i find I will let you know !